# Conexão de um servidor local para um externo com js e php

Tags: php, javascript, servidor, conexão

Minha intenção é, pelo servidor local, consultar dados em um servidor externo. Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer com que o servidor externo ficasse esperando a conexão local e dependendo dessa conexão local, tomar decisões diferentes.

Exemplo: tenho 2 clientes e 1 servidor, preciso conectar esses clientes com o servidor e o servidor deve responder de forma diferenciada para cada cliente. Como posso fazer isso só com php e javascript? A lógica eu sei, não sei é como estabelecer essa conexão.

Não estou pedindo código pronto, quero apenas saber os meios de como fazer.

Comment: Podes dar um url com hashs diferentes uma para cada cliente, ou dar páginas diferentes. Algo que impeça isso? ou fazer login. Podes explicar melhor que parte não sabes fazer?

Comment: Bom, você pode simplesmente criar uma url tipo `meusite.com/c=1`e fazer o tratamento com o php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Como fazer**

Você pode fazer o uso de [WebServices](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), você pode efetuar troca de mensagens ([JSON](http://json.org/json-pt.html)). Para efetuar a comunicação do client (servidor local) com o servidor remoto (onde ficaria os webservices junto ao banco de dados).

**Como diferenciar um client de outro e tecnologias para auxiliar/agilizar o desenvolvimento**

Para diferenciar um client de outro você pode fazer o uso de parâmetros nas requisições [AJAX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29), hoje há frameworks javascript que facilitam a maneira de fazer essas requisições como o ([jQuery](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) e o [AngularJS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS)).

> Como você disse que tem conhecimento da lógica, você pode trabalhar com os métodos/tecnologias citados acima para alcançar seu objetivo.